# Como faço em Python para validar a coluna de produto versus seu imposto correspondente pelo arquivo xlsx

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

Olá, pessoal, boa noite! Sou nova na comunidade e preciso de auxilio para solucionar um código.

Tenho uma planilha em Excel com diversos produtos e suas respectivas alíquotas de impostos. Só que não!

Logo, preciso retornar  os produtos que não possuem alíquota ou que possuem alíquota incorreta.
Exemplo: Para o produto perfume o correto é alíquota de 18%, se na planilha tiver != constando tipo 16% esse produto deverá ser a saída do meu programa e sua alíquota incorreta.

Nessa base do Excel tenho 50.000 linhas com produtos cadastrados, preciso encontrar uma forma mais automática e rápida de executar esse tipo de validação que possa fazer a leitura de linha por linha, retornando apenas o que for invalido.

Estou começando a aprender Python agora (iniciante total) então gostaria que a ajuda viesse nessa linguagem.

```
Import pandas as pd
#importando a planilha para um panda Datafreme
df = pd.read_excel('plan1.xls',sheet_name='Sheet1')

#Selecionando os produto em um set
CategoriaProdutos = set(list(df['CategoriaProduto']))
```

Só consegui escrever até aqui!

Como a mesma instrução de validação deverá ser executada várias vezes seguidas para os produtos do arquivo xlsx, entendo que, precisarei de um laço de repetição `for` ou `while` que possa executar o mesmo bloco de código para retornar a condição desejada.

'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

para análise de arquivos excel eu recomendo o openpyxl: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html

Veja abaixo um uso simples dessa lib.

```
>>> from openpyxl import load_workbook
>>> wb = load_workbook(filename = 'empty_book.xlsx')
>>> sheet_ranges = wb['range names']
>>> print(sheet_ranges['D18'].value)
3
```

No seu caso em específico, de uma maneira bem simples faria algo:

```
prosseguir = True
x = 1
while prosseguir == True:
  campo = sheet_ranges["D" + x].value
  if campo == "":
    break
  
  # caso o valor do campo seja em float ex: 0.18, necessário converter
  elif float(campo) == 0.18:
    # aqui neste caso você teria que informar o campo com o nome do produto
    # vamos supor que esteja na coluna E
    print("Produto fora da alíquota: {}".format(sheet_ranges["E" + x].value))

  # caso texto ex: 16%
  elif campo != "18%":
    # aqui neste caso você teria que informar o campo com o nome do produto
    # vamos supor que esteja na coluna E
    print("Produto fora da alíquota: {}".format(sheet_ranges["E" + x].value))

  x += 1
```

Espero ter ajudado, montei da maneira mais simples que pude pensar

Comment: Obrigada pela resposta!

Comment: Sou de Piracicaba e estou precisando de um mentor para o meu segundo projeto se for o caso, estou até disposta a pagar para ter conhecimento e desenvolver na pratica mais rápido. Porque estou tentando desenvolver um programa mais não tenho experiencia alguma.

Comment: Caso tenhas mais dúvidas pode solicitar ajuda aos grupos do telegram também https://t.me/pythonbr lá possui muitos desenvolvedores, novatos e curiosos que podem lhe ajudar em relação ao python. Se quiser me enviar dúvidas e eu estiver online pode me chamar https://t.me/WellingtonCesarFonseca